# Matlab Script Problem between Linux and Windows

Tags: linux, matlab

I wrote a script in Matlab on windows system. Now I changed to linux system and I tried to use my script on linux in matlab also. But it does not work.

I got a problem with the data import part of my script:

```
data = {};            
for i = 1:numel(filelist)  
  filename = filelist{i}; 
  filename = [selpath '\' filename];
  delimiter = ',';
  startRow = 2;
  formatSpec = '%*q%*q%*q%q%[^\n\r]';
  fileID = fopen(filename,'r');
  dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'TextType', 'string', 'HeaderLines' ,startRow-1, 'ReturnOnError', false, 'EndOfLine', '\r\n');
  fclose(fileID);
  tmp_data = str2double(dataArray{1}); 
  data{i} = tmp_data; 
end
```

If I run my script I got the following error from matlab:

```
Error using textscan
Invalid file identifier. Use fopen to generate a valid file   identifier.

Error in justus_tem (line 21)
dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'TextType', 'string', 'HeaderLines' ,startRow-1, 'ReturnOnError',
false, 'EndOfLine', '\r\n');
```

When I run the same script on windows I do not get the Error. In linux system the `fileID` is always `-1`
Has somebody a tip or knows what I do wrong? I tried different permissions for `fopen` but it does not work either.

Comment: Did you try seeing what the variable `filename` contains in Linux?

Comment: Therefore most programming languages have something like https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filesep.html

Answer (score 1):

Linux uses a forward slash (`/`) as the file separator, you have hard-coded the Windows compatible backward slash (`\`). Instead, consider either

1. Using `filesep` for a system-dependent file separator

```
filename = [selpath, filesep, filename];
```

2. Or use `fullfile` to build the path for you

```
filename = fullfile(selpath, filename);
```